# How do I create a schema for a typical college framework?

Tags: database-design

I have two tables:

### Departments

> PK: DeptId

| DeptId | DeptName |
| --- | --- |

### Faculties

> PK: FacultyId
> FK: DeptId

| FacultyId | FacultyName | DeptId |
| --- | --- | --- |

---

What I want is to add another column in the `Departments` table called `HOD` which will hold the Id of the Faculty who's the HOD of the Department. I was thinking that I'll have to make the `FacultyId` a ForeignKey in the `Deparments` table. However, that'll create a cyclic dependency.

---

How do I go about creating my Tables in this situation?

Comment: HOD is an attribute of the faculty and hence must be stored in Faculties as boolean column. If you need to restrict that not more than one faculty is HOD then use trigger logic which, when you set some facility as HOD, disables HOD for all another facilities of this department. *However, that'll create a cyclic dependency.* No, there is no cycle in such case.

Comment: @Akina, *no cycle in such case*, which case are you talking about? The one I have mentioned or the better one which you've suggested?

Comment: @Akina you say: `and hence must be stored in Faculties as boolean column` - this is incorrect AFAICS - the OP says: `which will hold the Id of the Faculty who's the HOD of the Department.` which makes sense to me! AFAIK, **normally** university departements have their **own** heads - and that person **may** or **may not** also be the faculty head? I'd have a faculty head (ID - FK into a staff table) field for the faculty table and the same for departement head!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW, that is what I thought. But I don't know how accurate I was

Comment: *which case are you talking about?* I mean that the situation when column1 in table1 refers to column2 in table2 and column 3 in table2 refers to column4 in table1 is not enough for cycle. For example, additional (trigger) logic may provide that ref. values for column4 are posessed in the same row in which the initial value for column1 is stored.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW Faculty may be either head or regular. Its posession in department structure is not a property of department. *normally university departements have their own heads - and that person may or may not also be the faculty head?* Normally the person is a head of faculty.

Comment: @Akina I'm not sure exactly what you mean? Maybe universities are organised differently in Russia to in Ireland? For example, in Trinity College Dublin (organigram [here](https://www.tcd.ie/structure/)), there is the faculty of Science, Technology, Engineering, and Mathematics (STEM - very trendy word these days) and there are 8 schools within that (Biochem + Immunology, Genetics + Micro, Comp Sci + Stats...) and then into their separate depts - **all of which** have heads - faculty head more prestigious than dept. head. [UCD](https://www.ucd.ie/colleges.htm) similar (Faculty = "College").

Comment: @Akina, in my use case, the Department head *is* a faculty member (Faculty includes only the Teachers, Lecturers, Professors, Assistant Professors and Associate Professors). Even the Principal is actually a professor and teaches a subject!

Comment: *in my use case, the Department head is a faculty member* In this case you have many-to-many relation. A person may be at the same time (formally) both a head of department and a member or even head (I have told - formally, I doubt that there exists some restrictional rule) of a faculty. This M:N relation needs in junction table or EAV attribute table. But anycase the position and the person holding this position are different things. So the fact that some person holds the head posession is an attribute of this person.

Comment: Am I missing something here ? That design looks like there is a foreign key *from faculty to departmen*t ? I.e. there is a one-to-many relationship between departments and faculties ? I.e. a *department has many faculties* ? That's odd. I would have thought the opposite, as Vérace indicated ...

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, That's right. Department has many Faculties. Here Faculty is an Individual who teaches in the Department

Comment: "Faculty is an Individual who teaches in the Department". Then why don't you call that table something like STAFF ? It would make it clearer. Terminology is very important.

Comment: So, considering that the `faculty` table really stores people, let's call is `staff`. Then yes, it makes sense to have a one-to-many relationship between `departments ` and `staff`, and therefore a foreign key from `staff` to `departments` to express the fact an individual can manage several departments.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, um if I call it Staff, shouldn't it include everyone in the department and not just the people who teach? i.e., the people who sort documents, those who create the templates for documents which the dept needs, those who are assistants to the professors (and not assistant professor, which good ol' Dwight would want everyone to believe :D ), and so on?

Comment: Well, that is up to you - or rather up to the problem you need to solve. If you want to restrict the humans involved to just teachers, then call the table `teachers`. Like I said, terminology and naming is important: not for the database itself (you can call tables `T1` and `T2` it will work just as well) but for whoever looks at your design and your code after you.

Comment: `Teacher`... Now why didn't I think of that? That'll do :) Thanks loads @AlbertGodfrind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131109/discussion-between-kesarling-he-him-and-albert-godfrind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the faculty table really stores **people**, let's call is **staff**. Then yes, it makes sense to have a one-to-many relationship between **departments** and **staff**, and therefore a foreign key from **staff** to **departments** to express the fact an individual can manage several departments.

The problem is that you cannot create both tables with their foreign keys pre-defined: that will obviously fail since each refers to the other. The proper steps are therefore:

1. Create the tables
2. Populate them
3. Add the foreign key constraints.

Here is an example that uses a simple HR schema with `EMPLOYEES` and `DEPARTMENTS`. All employees work in a department, and some employees also manage one or more departments. This is using Oracle syntax, but you can easily transpose to any relational database.

Note that an employee **must** belong to a department. But an department can exist without any manager. To make it mandatory for a department to always have a manager, you need to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to the `MANAGER_ID` column.

Note also that a manager could manage multiple departments (even though the sample data does not have such a case).

Create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE departments ( 
  department_id    NUMBER primary key,
  department_name  VARCHAR2(30), 
  manager_id       NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE employees (
  employee_id    NUMBER primary key,
  first_name     VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(25), 
  email          VARCHAR2(25), 
  phone_number   VARCHAR2(20),
  department_id  NUMBER NOT NULL
);
```

Populate departments:

```
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (10,'Administration',200);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (20,'Marketing',201);                                
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (30,'Purchasing',114);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (40,'Human Resources',203);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (50,'Shipping',121);                
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (60 ,'IT',103);                
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (70 ,'Public Relations',204);                
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (80 ,'Sales',145);                
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (90 ,'Executive',100);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (100 ,'Finance',108);                
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (110 ,'Accounting',205);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (120 ,'Treasury',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (130 ,'Corporate Tax',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (140 ,'Control And Credit',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (150 ,'Shareholder Services',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (160 ,'Benefits',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (170 ,'Manufacturing',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (180 ,'Construction',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (190 ,'Contracting',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (200 ,'Operations',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (210 ,'IT Support',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (220 ,'NOC',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (230 ,'IT Helpdesk',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (240 ,'Government Sales',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (250 ,'Retail Sales',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (260 ,'Recruiting',NULL);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (270 ,'Payroll',NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Populate employees:

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (100,'Steven','King','SKING','515.123.4567',90);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (101,'Neena','Kochhar','NKOCHHAR','515.123.4568',90);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (102,'Lex','De Haan','LDEHAAN','515.123.4569',90);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (103,'Alexander','Hunold','AHUNOLD','590.423.4567',60);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (104,'Bruce','Ernst','BERNST','590.423.4568',60);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (105,'David','Austin','DAUSTIN','590.423.4569',60);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (106,'Valli','Pataballa','VPATABAL','590.423.4560',60);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (107,'Diana','Lorentz','DLORENTZ','590.423.5567',60);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (108,'Nancy','Greenberg','NGREENBE','515.124.4569',100);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (109,'Daniel','Faviet','DFAVIET','515.124.4169',100);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (110,'John','Chen','JCHEN','515.124.4269',100);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (111,'Ismael','Sciarra','ISCIARRA','515.124.4369',100);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (112,'Jose Manuel','Urman','JMURMAN','515.124.4469',100);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (113,'Luis','Popp','LPOPP','515.124.4567',100);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (114,'Den','Raphaely','DRAPHEAL','515.127.4561',30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (115,'Alexander','Khoo','AKHOO','515.127.4562',30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (116,'Shelli','Baida','SBAIDA','515.127.4563',30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (117,'Sigal','Tobias','STOBIAS','515.127.4564',30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (118,'Guy','Himuro','GHIMURO','515.127.4565',30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (119,'Karen','Colmenares','KCOLMENA','515.127.4566',30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (120,'Matthew','Weiss','MWEISS','650.123.1234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (121,'Adam','Fripp','AFRIPP','650.123.2234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (122,'Payam','Kaufling','PKAUFLIN','650.123.3234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (123,'Shanta','Vollman','SVOLLMAN','650.123.4234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (124,'Kevin','Mourgos','KMOURGOS','650.123.5234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (125,'Julia','Nayer','JNAYER','650.124.1214',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (126,'Irene','Mikkilineni','IMIKKILI','650.124.1224',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (127,'James','Landry','JLANDRY','650.124.1334',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (128,'Steven','Markle','SMARKLE','650.124.1434',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (129,'Laura','Bissot','LBISSOT','650.124.5234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (130,'Mozhe','Atkinson','MATKINSO','650.124.6234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (131,'James','Marlow','JAMRLOW','650.124.7234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (132,'TJ','Olson','TJOLSON','650.124.8234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (133,'Jason','Mallin','JMALLIN','650.127.1934',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (134,'Michael','Rogers','MROGERS','650.127.1834',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (135,'Ki','Gee','KGEE','650.127.1734',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (136,'Hazel','Philtanker','HPHILTAN','650.127.1634',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (137,'Renske','Ladwig','RLADWIG','650.121.1234',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (138,'Stephen','Stiles','SSTILES','650.121.2034',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (139,'John','Seo','JSEO','650.121.2019',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (140,'Joshua','Patel','JPATEL','650.121.1834',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (141,'Trenna','Rajs','TRAJS','650.121.8009',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (142,'Curtis','Davies','CDAVIES','650.121.2994',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (143,'Randall','Matos','RMATOS','650.121.2874',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (144,'Peter','Vargas','PVARGAS','650.121.2004',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (145,'John','Russell','JRUSSEL','011.44.1344.429268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (146,'Karen','Partners','KPARTNER','011.44.1344.467268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (147,'Alberto','Errazuriz','AERRAZUR','011.44.1344.429278',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (148,'Gerald','Cambrault','GCAMBRAU','011.44.1344.619268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (149,'Eleni','Zlotkey','EZLOTKEY','011.44.1344.429018',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (150,'Peter','Tucker','PTUCKER','011.44.1344.129268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (151,'David','Bernstein','DBERNSTE','011.44.1344.345268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (152,'Peter','Hall','PHALL','011.44.1344.478968',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (153,'Christopher','Olsen','COLSEN','011.44.1344.498718',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (154,'Nanette','Cambrault','NCAMBRAU','011.44.1344.987668',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (155,'Oliver','Tuvault','OTUVAULT','011.44.1344.486508',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (156,'Janette','King','JKING','011.44.1345.429268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (157,'Patrick','Sully','PSULLY','011.44.1345.929268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (158,'Allan','McEwen','AMCEWEN','011.44.1345.829268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (159,'Lindsey','Smith','LSMITH','011.44.1345.729268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (160,'Louise','Doran','LDORAN','011.44.1345.629268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (161,'Sarath','Sewall','SSEWALL','011.44.1345.529268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (162,'Clara','Vishney','CVISHNEY','011.44.1346.129268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (163,'Danielle','Greene','DGREENE','011.44.1346.229268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (164,'Mattea','Marvins','MMARVINS','011.44.1346.329268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (165,'David','Lee','DLEE','011.44.1346.529268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (166,'Sundar','Ande','SANDE','011.44.1346.629268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (167,'Amit','Banda','ABANDA','011.44.1346.729268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (168,'Lisa','Ozer','LOZER','011.44.1343.929268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (169,'Harrison','Bloom','HBLOOM','011.44.1343.829268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (170,'Tayler','Fox','TFOX','011.44.1343.729268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (171,'William','Smith','WSMITH','011.44.1343.629268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (172,'Elizabeth','Bates','EBATES','011.44.1343.529268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (173,'Sundita','Kumar','SKUMAR','011.44.1343.329268',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (174,'Ellen','Abel','EABEL','011.44.1644.429267',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (175,'Alyssa','Hutton','AHUTTON','011.44.1644.429266',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (176,'Jonathon','Taylor','JTAYLOR','011.44.1644.429265',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (177,'Jack','Livingston','JLIVINGS','011.44.1644.429264',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (178,'Kimberely','Grant','KGRANT','011.44.1644.429263',NULL);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (179,'Charles','Johnson','CJOHNSON','011.44.1644.429262',80);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (180,'Winston','Taylor','WTAYLOR','650.507.9876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (181,'Jean','Fleaur','JFLEAUR','650.507.9877',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (182,'Martha','Sullivan','MSULLIVA','650.507.9878',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (183,'Girard','Geoni','GGEONI','650.507.9879',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (184,'Nandita','Sarchand','NSARCHAN','650.509.1876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (185,'Alexis','Bull','ABULL','650.509.2876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (186,'Julia','Dellinger','JDELLING','650.509.3876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (187,'Anthony','Cabrio','ACABRIO','650.509.4876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (188,'Kelly','Chung','KCHUNG','650.505.1876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (189,'Jennifer','Dilly','JDILLY','650.505.2876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (190,'Timothy','Gates','TGATES','650.505.3876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (191,'Randall','Perkins','RPERKINS','650.505.4876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (192,'Sarah','Bell','SBELL','650.501.1876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (193,'Britney','Everett','BEVERETT','650.501.2876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (194,'Samuel','McCain','SMCCAIN','650.501.3876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (195,'Vance','Jones','VJONES','650.501.4876',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (196,'Alana','Walsh','AWALSH','650.507.9811',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (197,'Kevin','Feeney','KFEENEY','650.507.9822',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (198,'Donald','OConnell','DOCONNEL','650.507.9833',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (199,'Douglas','Grant','DGRANT','650.507.9844',50);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (200,'Jennifer','Whalen','JWHALEN','515.123.4444',10);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (201,'Michael','Hartstein','MHARTSTE','515.123.5555',20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (202,'Pat','Fay','PFAY','603.123.6666',20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (203,'Susan','Mavris','SMAVRIS','515.123.7777',40);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (204,'Hermann','Baer','HBAER','515.123.8888',70);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (205,'Shelley','Higgins','SHIGGINS','515.123.8080',110);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (206,'William','Gietz','WGIETZ','515.123.8181',110);
COMMIT;
```

Add foreign key constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD CONSTRAINT fk_employees_departments department_id REFERENCES departments;

ALTER TABLE departments ADD CONSTRAINT fk_departments_employees manager_id REFERENCES employees;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful :) By any Chance, is it possible you know how to do this with EF Core? 

Comment: Also, about the `NOT NULL` constraint, I will have to add it later while creating the foreign keys, right?

Comment: You can add the NOT NULL constraint directly when creating the table: `manager_id number not null`. That means those departments without any manager  - like `INSERT INTO departments VALUES (220 ,'NOC',NULL);` will fail.

Comment: but if the `manager_id` is not nullable, what value of Employee ID will I insert? Because, as employee_dept_id in also not nullable, I'll need a dept_id, which will need the manager_id, which will require employee_id and so on... (Sorry for asking repeatedly, but I'm kind of confused)

Comment: [Just like I predicted](https://imgur.com/a/g68cFRT) 